# Bash - Same command substitution output, but different when echo'ed

Tags: bash, escaping, echo, backslash, command-substitution

This is confounding. I need an explanation of the factor at work here which I'm apparently missing.

`echo \\z`

yields:

`\z`

`echo \\\z`

also yields:

`\z`

Ok fine (presumably because of the way backslashes in command line escaping are discarded even if the character being escaped would not have been treated specially anyway).

But

```
echo `echo \\z`
```

yields:

`z`

whereas

```
echo `echo \\\z`
```

yields:

`\z`

So, both command substitutions yield `\z` (when their command runs outside of a command substitution), but yet when run as command substitutions, when you `echo` the result of one of them, it produces a different result to `echo`ing the result of the other.

WTF?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408507/can-someone-explain-the-strange-behavior-of-backslash-in-command-substitution

Comment: Escapes are processed weirdly inside of backticks before they're even passed to the `echo` command; use `$( )` instead. See [BashFAQ #82](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150970/why-can-back-quotes-and-for-command-substitution-result-in-different-output)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I believe I see what's occurring now. But will indeed use `$( )` instead :).