# sed results different when using bash variables

Tags: bash, shell, sed

A test file has the following string:

```
$ cat testfile
x is a \xtest string
```

The following script attempts to replace escape sequence: `\x` occurrences with `yy` using `sed`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Printing directly to stdout"
sed -e "s/\\\x/yy/g" testfile
var1=`sed -e "s/\\\x/yy/g" testfile`
echo "Printing from variable"
echo "${var1}"
```

As it can be seen below, the results are different when it is printed with and without saving to a temporary variable. Could someone help me understand why this happens?
I'd want the variable to hold the string that has replaced only `\x`

```
Printing directly to stdout
x is a yytest string
Printing from variable
yy is a \yytest string
```

Platform: macOS

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: You should normally put sed expressions in single quotes rather than double quotes. Then you don't need to double the backslashes.

Comment: The reason this happens is because backticks process backslash escapes.

Comment: @Barmar I see. Would it be better to use `$()` instead of backticks for all command evaluations? Or are there cases where backticks are preferred over `$()`?

Comment: Backticks are effectively obsolete, there's no time they're preferred.

Comment: Unless you need portability to 30 year old systems.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You could add the response as an answer and I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: You may want to read [Why is $(...) preferred over \`...\` (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: Someone else already answered.

Comment: This looks like a possible duplicate of ["Why does my Perl one-liner containing an escaped $ not work inside Bash backticks?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753503/why-does-my-perl-one-liner-containing-an-escaped-not-work-inside-bash-backtick) and/or ["Why can back-quotes and $() for command substitution result in different output?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150970/why-can-back-quotes-and-for-command-substitution-result-in-different-output)

Comment: @seriousgeek if the answer solved your problem, please accept it. Note that you don't need to upvote it, but please do accept it as it also marks for future readers: "try this, it helped me solve my problem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your command inside a `$(...)` like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Printing directly to stdout"
sed -e "s/\\\x/yy/g" testfile
var1=$(sed -e "s/\\\x/yy/g" testfile)
echo "Printing from variable"
echo "${var1}"
```

Comment: You should explain why this makes a difference.